# What is the possessive form of "Macy's"?

Tags: grammar, possessives

Basic rules:

```
For a singular noun ending with no "s," we add an apostrophe and s at the end.<br />
For a plural noun ending with no "s," we add an apostrophe and s at the end.<br />
For a singular noun ending with an "s," we add an apostrophe only.<br />
```

But some names of companies have already ended with an apostrophe and s; I wonder what the grammatical rule is to form the possessive of such a word.

For example, Macy's is a big brand headquartered in New York City.
What's the possessive form of Macy's?

There's a similar question. [Possessive of a possessive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31242/possessive-of-a-possessive)

But the answers to that question didn't give out a definite rule.
I want to know whether there is a rule in the grammar book about how to deal with the situation similar to "Macy's."

I have tried *Longman Advanced Learners' Grammer*, but I didn't find the relative rule.

Comment: **Macy's** is already the possessive form.  You can think of it like a short way of saying **Macy's store**.

Comment: @BillyKerr Great. Your explanation sounds reasonable.

Comment: I've never seen Macy's's or similar. You may never find the definite rule that you're looking for. But note that company names can often have a possessive quality, let's call it, without the 's. For example, you could say either "Microsoft CEO" or "Microsoft's CEO"; either term refers to the same person. I think of "Macy's CEO" as being analogous to "Microsoft CEO."